# Updating appointments using EWS

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm creating an application which will put a CSV file into Exchange, which works perfectly.

However, when the timetable has changed and my application ran, it will insert double calendar items.

I have 2 possible solutions:

1. Deleting all calendar items which contain a certain body text
2. Updating the already made appointments

Which option do you prefer and how would this be done? In each case I need the `itemID` of a specific appointment and I have no idea how get this `itemID`.

Comment: Check  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972311/how-to-update-an-appointment-from-exchange-web-service-managed-api-2-0-in-asp-ne/13986827#13986827

Answer (score 0):

I've done the following:

```
CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(dtStart, dtEnd);
var Appointments = service.FindAppointments(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, calendarView);

foreach (Appointment app in items)
{
    if (app.Body.Text.Trim() == "Timetable")
    {
        app.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete);
    }
}
```

Works perfectly, might be a little slow but not important in my case :-)