# Exchange Webservice Managed API - Find items by extended properties

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have tried to use extended properties on appointments with EWS, but I can not seem to find the appointments again. The set property part is equal to the one shown in this question:

[How to Update an Appointment from Exchange Web Service Managed API 2.0 in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972311/how-to-update-an-appointment-from-exchange-web-service-managed-api-2-0-in-asp-ne)

When I try to retrieve the appointment, I have followed these examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/uc14trainingcourse_5l_topic3#_Toc254008129
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633697(v=exchg.80).aspx

But I never get any appointments returned when I make a lookup.

Here is the code for the lookup:

```
        ItemView view = new ItemView(10);

        // Get the GUID for the property set.
        Guid MyPropertySetId = new Guid("{" + cGuid + "}");

        // Create a definition for the extended property.
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedPropertyDefinition =
          new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(MyPropertySetId, "AppointmentID", MapiPropertyType.String);

        view.PropertySet =
         new PropertySet(
               BasePropertySet.IdOnly,
               ItemSchema.Subject,
               AppointmentSchema.Start,
               AppointmentSchema.End, extendedPropertyDefinition);

        SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.Exists(extendedPropertyDefinition);

        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, filter,
            view);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
When I try to create the property like the documentation shows:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633654(v=exchg.80).aspx

It fails because its a Guid im adding as property value. :-/

**Edit again:**
Just tried getting all appointments for today, and getting the property from the appointment I just created, and it says the same as I stored, without the {}, so it must be somthing with the filter.

**Edit once again***
It has somthing to do with

```
 ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedProperty = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(
```

if I use:

```
 new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(
                DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Appointment,
                "AppointmentID",
                MapiPropertyType.String);
```

It finds all the appointments with properties, but if I search for a specific one:

```
 Guid MyPropertySetId = new Guid("{" + cGuid + "}");

 ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedProperty =
            new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(
                MyPropertySetId,
                "AppointmentID",
                MapiPropertyType.String);
```

Then nothing is found.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

here's a samplecode how to create an appointment with the customid and find it after saving:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
        service.AutodiscoverUrl("someone@somewhere.com");

        ExtendedPropertyDefinition def = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "AppointmenId", MapiPropertyType.String);

        Guid testid = Guid.NewGuid ();

        Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
        appointment.Subject = "Test";
        appointment.Start = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
        appointment.End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
        appointment.SetExtendedProperty(def, testid.ToString());
        appointment.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);

        SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(def, testid.ToString());

        FindItemsResults<Item> fir = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, filter, new ItemView(10));
```

hope this helps you...

Comment: your welcome... maybe next time you can help me ;)
can you please set the "was helpfull" ;)

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187481/should-i-use-guid-or-defaultextendedpropertyset-publicstrings-while-constructing you should always use your own property set id, to avoid collision with properties set by other vendors. Still love your quick solution!

Answer (score 0):

You search the inbox for appointments. There you will never find them. Try to search in the Calendar instead.

Comment: Yes, I was searching in the wrong folder, but it still finds nothing :-/

Comment: hmm... maybe it's because of the way how your create your propertydefinition.
try this code:
                ExtendedPropertyDefinition propdef = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, name, MapiPropertyType.String);

for adding and searching. I had some Problems using the Guid-way too. This one is easier and works perferct in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of putting the guid as extension property and getting the appointment based on the guid.

```
private static readonly PropertyDefinitionBase AppointementIdPropertyDefinition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "AppointmentID", MapiPropertyType.String);
public static PropertySet PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, AppointementIdPropertyDefinition);


//Setting the property for the appointment 
 public static void SetGuidForAppointement(Appointment appointment)
{
    try
    {
        appointment.SetExtendedProperty((ExtendedPropertyDefinition)AppointementIdPropertyDefinition, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        appointment.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // logging the exception
    }
}

//Getting the property for the appointment
 public static string GetGuidForAppointement(Appointment appointment)
{
    var result = "";
    try
    {
        appointment.Load(PropertySet);
        foreach (var extendedProperty in appointment.ExtendedProperties)
        {
            if (extendedProperty.PropertyDefinition.Name == "AppointmentID")
            {
                result = extendedProperty.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
     // logging the exception
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is the code I am using for setting the Guid. The second part retrieves the guid from an appointment. My problem is I need to find the specific appointment when only having the Guid.

Comment: well, when you find the appointments from certain dates to others, then you apply an if case searching among them using the Guid which you extract if it matches or not.